# What is the difference betweem daemon-reload and reload?

Tags: systemd, services

daemon-reload - Load the unit configuration file of the running designated unit(s) to make
unit file configuration changes without stopping the service. Note that
this is different from the reload command

reload - Load the service configuration file of the running designated unit(s) to
make service configuration changes without stopping the service. Note
that this is different from the daemon-reload command.

What is unit and service here ? For example apache2.service is a unit with service type . Then what is service in the above description ??

Answer (score 8):

`daemon-reload` will reload systemd files. If you change a service file in `/etc/systemd/system/`, `daemon-reload` will reload these files.

For instance, you realize that you need a 5 seconds timeout between restarts in a service. You add that timeout in a service file and make a `daemon-reload`. That will cause a timeout on next service restart. Service configuration will not be affected by that change.

`reload` will reload a specific service. That means that the systemd will send a SIGHUP signal to a service, and that signal will tell the service to reload its configuration files, which has nothing to do with systemd config files.

For instance, apache has a file `httpd.conf`. With `reload`, systemd will send a SIGHUP to a running apache to tell it to reload the configuration file. However, that will not change anything, how the service is treated by systemd.

With `reload` you have to provide additional parameter(s), telling which services will receive SIGHUP signal. With `daemon-reload` you do not provide any additional parameters, as systemd will check all its service files for changes and reload them.

It is not written in manual, but I guess a service has to support reloading in order to make reload successful. Otherwise, you have to restart it to force it to reload configuration.

Comment: So daemon reload reloads the units with recent changes . But reload reloads specific service. Am I correct.

Comment: @teja_M19 Yes. `deamon-reload` does not affect running services in any way. `daemon-reload` is a reload for systemd, while `reload` is a reload for a specific service.

Comment: Cool .  Thanks Man ✌️✌️